# Is it possible to send REGISTER message without expire header in SIP

Tags: sip, registration

Scenario : UE is Registered with expire value 3600 and now we want to simulate, now we will will send the REGISTER message without Expire header and expire parameter. what would be result in 200 ok ?

Regards,
Yogesh

Answer (score 1):

The spec [mandates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10.3) that the registrar uses a locally configured expiration value which is sent back in the expires parameter of the Contact(s).